# css div left and right unwanted line

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to do a bit customizing based on the Twenty Thirteen theme.
I made also customized the footer, also inserted a div that should seperate it.
As can be seen there white thin lines on the left and right of the div, as i zoom in they disappear. I dont really have a clue what causes that.

[image]

```
footer code

    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
?>

    </div><!-- #main -->
    <div id="footer-separator"></div>
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

        <div class="site-info">
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

as well as the css

```
#footer-separator {
height: 20px;
width: auto;
background-color: #383b3a;
}
```

Would appreciate a hint how to get rid of those lines.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my end...

Comment: On Chrome I had to zoom out to 90%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.site {
    border: none;
}
```

If you inspect the element, the div (with class `hfeed site`) that surrounds all of that content has a border applied. Remove this border and you should be good.

Comment: thank you! was to focused to look at the other elements. btw upvoted it, now there is a -1, sorry about that, cant change it. will check later again.

Comment: it does for me. why do you think it doesnt resolve the issue?

Comment: Because you can see in the inspector that that element doesn't have borders, and if I add this suggestion nothing changes.

Comment: It had borders when I answered the question originally. @telema334 did you apply the fix already?

Comment: I can see the new CSS, but the line still appears. See the image I just added to your question. That's Chrome at 250%, but it appears at all zoom levels for me.

Comment: i checked now with chrome, edge and firefox. cant reproduce it anymore on any zoom level. strange that you still see it.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to sub-pixel rounding, where the `#fff` background of the parent element shows. Instead of putting the background color on `.site`, maybe put it on the inner elements, such as `.site-main`.